# iTunes connect: Cannot find the upload the mac os x app icon

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect

It's been few days now that I have been looking for the section where you upload the Icon.

I have done this for iphones and it is in the modal screen when you clik edit.

Mac has very similar Itunes connect interface, but that piece is missing for me:

[image]

Im so confused, please advise. Here is the default icon:

[image]

Comment: ITunes connect reads app icon from bundle afer app uploaded. It gets couple minutes to update.

Comment: @mohacs But I have not submitted yet. are you saying once I submit it will update the icon?

Comment: yes it is correct, once you uploaded your binary, in couple minutes you will see the icon there. during the upload if there is missing icon it warns you.

Comment: @mohacs ok I just submitted , and now I get `Invalid Binary`

Comment: did you put your icons in to Images.xcassets/AppIcon/? Icons couldn't not be the only reason to get that warning. Is there any error code/message follows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the related documentation, it states:

> If you are adding an OS X app, the Uploads section displays only one
>   option, Desktop Screenshot, which is required and shown next. You will
>   not be asked to provide a large icon when adding your OS X app because
>   it will be uploaded later as part of the binary.

[Documentation Link](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html)

Comment: You were right! I guess my confusion comes from the ios process being different, once I sandboxed and submitted, the icon appear. Thanks A lot !!